# Syntax for passing values to a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, precision, type-conversion

I'm new to writing triggers and functions in Postgres.

I have written a function that changes prices to .99 or .00 whenever a price is put into the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cents(price numeric)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 LEAKPROOF
AS $function$
DECLARE
   dollars text;
   cents text;
   new_price numeric;
BEGIN
   dollars := split_part(price::text, '.', 1);
   cents := split_part(price::text, '.', 2);
   IF cents != '00' THEN cents := '99';
   ENDIF;
   new_price := dollars || '.' || cents;
   RETURN new_price;
END;
$function$
```

I've read the [doc on triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) and these examples seem more complex.

I'm not sure I understand how to create a trigger that will run this function specifically whenever a record in the price column is updated.

Does this look correct? The price column isn't mentioned in the trigger..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cents()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 LEAKPROOF
AS $tr_cents$
DECLARE
   dollars text;
   cents text;
   new_price numeric;
BEGIN
   dollars := split_part(OLD::text, '.', 1);
   cents := split_part(OLD::text, '.', 2);
   IF cents != '00' THEN cents := '99';
   ENDIF;
   new_price := dollars || cents;
   RETURN new_price;
END;
$tr_cents$;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_cents BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON microwaves
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE cents();
```

The examples in the docs also use `RETURN NEW` but I'm not exactly sure how that would work with my code, or if it's necessary?

Comment: Please remember to disclose your version of Postgres and the relevant table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming missing information:

- `price` is defined **`numeric NOT NULL`**.
- There is a `CHECK` constraint enforcing ***positive*** prices.
- Postgres 9.5. (Solution should work for Postgres 9.0+.)

I read your ***objective*** like this:

***Leave numbers without (significant) fractional digits (`.00`) and change all others to `.99`.***

<sub>See below about "without (significant) fractional digits" or `.00` ...</sub>

If that's all the trigger does, the most efficient way is to place the condition in a `WHEN` clause to the *trigger* itself. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-NOTES)

> In a `BEFORE` trigger, the `WHEN` condition is evaluated just before the
>   function is or would be executed, so using `WHEN` is not materially
>   different from testing the same condition at the beginning of the trigger function.

(There is more, read the manual.)
This way, the *trigger function* is not even called if not needed. The logic can be **radically simplified**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_cents()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$tr_cents$
BEGIN
   -- only called WHEN (NEW.price % 1 IN (.00, .99)
   NEW.price := trunc(NEW.price) + .99;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$tr_cents$  LANGUAGE plpgsql LEAKPROOF;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER microwaves_cents
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON microwaves
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ((NEW.price % 1) <> ALL ('{.00,.99}'::numeric[]))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_cents();
```

Note that the trigger kicks in for `INSERT` *and* `UPDATE` with illegal price values. Not just

> whenever a record in the price column is updated.

You ***need*** `RETURN NEW;` at the end of the trigger function or the operation on the row will be cancelled. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> A trigger function must return either `NULL` or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.

You don't need the function `public.cents()` at all for this.

#### Test case

```
CREATE TABLE microwaves (m_id serial PRIMARY KEY, price numeric);

INSERT INTO microwaves (m_id, price) VALUES
     (1, 0.00)
   , (2, 0.01)
   , (3, 0.02)
   , (4, 0.99)
   , (5, 1.00)
   , (6, 1.01)
   , (7, 1.02)
   , (8, 1.99)
   , (9, 12.34);

UPDATE microwaves SET price = 2.0  WHERE m_id = 7;
UPDATE microwaves SET price = 2.5  WHERE m_id = 8;
UPDATE microwaves SET price = 5.99 WHERE m_id = 9;

TABLE microwaves;
```

Result:

```
 m_id | price
------+-------
    1 |  0.00
    2 |  0.99
    3 |  0.99
    4 |  0.99
    5 |  1.00
    6 |  1.99
    7 |   2.0
    8 |  2.99
    9 |  5.99
```

### Data type `numeric` and *scale*

.. and why your function `public.cents(price numeric)` is a ***trap***.

*Scale* being the number of decimal fractional digits.

`numeric` is an arbitrary precision type. It preserves literal digits exactly as entered - unless you specify *precision* and *scale* for the type. Like: `numeric(10,2)`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

> Specifying:
>
> ```
> NUMERIC
> ```
>
> without any precision or scale creates a column in which numeric
>   values of any precision and scale can be stored, up to the
>   implementation limit on precision. A column of this kind (numeric
>   without precision and scale) **will not coerce input values to any
>   particular scale**, whereas numeric columns with a declared scale will
>   coerce input  values to that scale.

Leading zeroes are never stored, but trailing zeroes in the fractional part are kept this way, even if *insignificant*. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) can easily be misread in this respect, further down:

> Numeric values are physically stored without any extra leading or trailing zeroes.

Note the word "*extra*". Meaning, Postgres will not *add* trailing zeros, but it will keep the ones you added - even if those are completely insignificant for the numeric value.

You need to be aware of this when converting `numeric` to `text`. A check for `"00"` in the fractional part will work for `numeric` with a configured scale like `numeric (9,2)`. But it is ***unreliable*** for plain `numeric` like you use in your function. Consider:

```
SELECT (numeric(9,2) '1')::numeric AS num_cast_from_num_with_scale
      , numeric '1.00'             AS num_with_scale
      , numeric '1'                AS num_without_scale;

 num_cast_from_num_with_scale | num_with_scale | num_without_scale
------------------------------+----------------+-------------------
                         1.00 |           1.00 |                 1
```

This way, *insignificant* trailing zeros become *significant*. And I seriously doubt that's how it's supposed to be. The test  `IF cents != '00' ...` in your function `public.cents(price numeric)` is a **loaded footgun**. It may work as expected while you pass values from a `numeric(9,2)` column, but "suddenly" break once you use values from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

You described return value as numeric, but return a string by fact. Also several type conversions not a good point. There is more easy way. F. ex.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cents(price numeric) RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
begin
    IF price IS NOT NULL then
        IF price % 1 != 0 then
            price := floor(price) + 0.99;
        end IF;
    END IF;
RETURN price;
end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To execute such update on any insert/update need:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    price numeric
);

CREATE FUNCTION price_update() RETURNS trigger AS $price_update$
    BEGIN

        IF NEW.price IS NOT NULL THEN
            NEW.price = public.cents(NEW.price);
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$price_update$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER on_price_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE price_update();
```

Lets check:

```
=# insert into test (price) values (2), (1.1), (5);
INSERT 0 3

=# select * from test;
 price 
-------
     2
  1.99
     5
(3 rows)

=# update test set price = 5.01 where price = 5;
UPDATE 1

=# select * from test;
 price 
-------
     2
  1.99
  5.99
(3 rows)

=# update test set price = 3 where price = 1.99;
UPDATE 1

=# select * from test;
 price 
-------
     2
  5.99
     3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I think you may have misread `IF cents != '00' THEN cents := '99';`

Comment: No. I checked it by `IF price % 1 = 0 then price := price + 0.99;  end IF;`. Price in your function described as numeric, so, we can check remainder of division on 1.

Comment: *My function*? I think you also misread my comment. I am not the OP. Checking the remainder is fine. I just think you inverted the logic. (Other sneaky problems aside, which aren't your fault.)

Comment: Oh, double sorry. Not yours function and correct, cents function should have other logic. My fault.

Comment: I fixed function in my answer.